Failed to Fetch Error When Connecting Dockerized Frontend to Dockerized Backend
I'm working on a project where both the frontend and backend are containerized using Docker. Everything works fine when running the frontend and backend locally without Docker. However, I encounter an issue when the frontend attempts to fetch data from the backend while in Docker. Specifically, route handling works well for API routes (e.g., /api/...) on the frontend, successfully sending requests to the backend and receiving responses. However, the problem arises when attempting to fetch data directly from the frontend to the backend.
I've confirmed that the environment variables are set correctly, and CORS is configured to accept all origins.
Here’s the fetch request I’m making to the backend:
const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR<PaginatedBoardsResponse>(
  `http://${process.env.SERVER_HOST}:${process.env.SERVER_PORT}/boards?tab=${activeTab}&page=${currentPage}&limit=${perPage}`,
  fetchBoards(accessToken as string),
  {
    revalidateOnFocus: true,
    keepPreviousData: true,
    revalidateIfStale: true,
  }
);

I initially suspected that useSWR might be causing the issue, but standard data fetching fails as well:
const BoardDetailsPage = async ({ params }: BoardDetailsPageProps) => {
  const boardData: BoardDetailsResponse = await getBoardDetailsData(params.boardId);
  return <BoardDetailsInfo board={boardData} />;
};

getBoardDetailsData:
import "server-only";

import { getCookie } from "@/lib/authApiUtils";
import { BoardDetailsResponse } from "@/interfaces/responses/board-details-response";
import { extractMessagesFromApiError } from "@/lib/toastsUtils";
import { ApiError } from "@/errors/ApiError";
import logger from "@/lib/logger";

export async function getBoardDetailsData(boardId: string): Promise<BoardDetailsResponse> {
  const accessToken = getCookie("accessToken");
  if (!accessToken) {
    throw new Error("User not authenticated.");
  }
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://${process.env.SERVER_HOST}:${process.env.SERVER_PORT}/boards/${boardId}/details`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      const reasons = await extractMessagesFromApiError(response);
      throw new ApiError(reasons);
    }

    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error("Error while fetching board details:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

Docker Compose Frontend Configuration:
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - SERVER_HOST=backend
      - SERVER_PORT=5000

  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

Any insights on why the direct data fetching from the frontend to the backend is failing within Docker would be greatly appreciated!

Are you hitting "Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend?  The actual frontend code is running in the end user's browser, not in a container, and from the browser the Docker-internal host names like backend won't resolve.  What is the actual error you're getting?

solved, thank you
